# Polymer - simple way to access child element properties from parent element

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

I have a simple polymer element that looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="selector-course">
  <template>
    <style>
        paper-dropdown-menu {
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Course">
      <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="value" id="courseSelect">
        <paper-item value="main">Main</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="soup">Soup</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="dessert">Dessert</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="appetizer">Appetizer</paper-item>
      </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'selector-course'
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This element is stored in a separate HTML file and then used in a couple of my other elements like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="components/selector-course.html">
...
<selector-course selected="{{recipe.course}}"></selector-course>
```

Now, within my parent elements I need to access the selected value of `<selector-course>`

Right now, I have a solution that looks like this:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('selector-course').shadowRoot.querySelector('#courseSelect').selectedItem.getAttribute("value");
```

This works, however, this query seems absurdly complex for such a trivial task as accessing the property of an element.

Is there a more simple way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh no, this is a very bad idea. Accessing internal elements is very brittle, because it requires parent elements to have deep (pun intended) knowledge about the implementation details of `<selector-course>`. Not to mention that your method will not work with Shady DOM.

In your case you could simply adding a notifying property to your element

```
Polymer({
  is: 'selector-course',
  properties: {
    selected: {
      notify: true
    }
  }
});
```

To select it's value outside data binding you can use the method @a1626 mentions

```
var selected = this.$('selector-course').selected;
```

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'selector-course',
  properties: {
    selected: {
      notify: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
  <link href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html" rel="import"/>
  <link href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html" rel="import"/>
  <link href="paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <template is="dom-bind">      
    <selector-course selected="{{selection}}"></selector-course>
    <div>{{selection}}</div>
  </template>
  
  <dom-module id="selector-course">
  <template>
    <style>
        paper-dropdown-menu {
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Course">
      <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="value" id="courseSelect">
        <paper-item value="main">Main</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="soup">Soup</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="dessert">Dessert</paper-item>
        <paper-item value="appetizer">Appetizer</paper-item>
      </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>
</dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neato. Exactly what I was looking for. The only problem was that I had to move {{recipe.course}} to a separate property, as two-way binding naturally didn't work if recipe property was empty.

Answer (score 6):

Your parent element seems to be a Polymer element in itself as you have used binding. In that case you can access property using

```
this.$.<id of child>.<property name>
```

Or in case your element is inside `dom-if` or `dom-repeat`

```
this.$$(<querySelector>).<property name>
```

You can check it out [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-$$)

In your case it'll be

```
<selector-course selected="{{selected}}" id="mySelector"></selector-course>
```

In javascript

```
this.$.selected
```

Comment: This is not a good advice, because it requires the consumer to be aware about element's internals. Web component should only be used with properties/attributes and events.

Comment: @TomaszPluskiewicz i've added code snippet to explain my answer better. Do you still feel the same about my answer?

Comment: Not any more. I misinterpreted your intention. However, I do think that it only solves part of the problem. The other is that the element in question doesn't actually have a `selected` property

Comment: It does but `notify` is not set to true as property is not mentioned in `properties` object in the constructor

Comment: Oh, good to know. I actually didn't realize that bound variables not mentioned in `properties` are also available on element level. Is that documented?

Comment: i doubt that. But it is extensively used in elements created by Polymer